# How to sort a django queryset when accessed via foreignkey in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have two models with a foreign key relation, when I loop through the Badge objects with `{% for badge in badge_type.badge_set.all %}` they are sorted by ID, however I want them sorted by by their `sort_order` or `name` fields, per the `Meta`

```
class BadgeType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class Badge(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    badge_type = models.ForeignKey(BadgeType)
    sort_order = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...

    class Meta:
        order_with_respect_to = 'badge_type'
        ordering = ['sort_order', 'name']
```

In a **view**, I am sending this in my context:

```
@login_required
def list(request):
    badge_types = BadgeType.objects.all()
    context = {"badge_types": badge_types,}
    return render(request, "badges/list.html" , context)
```

In the **template**:

```
{% for badge_type in badge_types %}
      {{badge_type.name}}

      {% for badge in badge_type.badge_set.all %}
          {{badge.name}}
      {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, in the template they are being ordered according to their ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this template filter:
[dictsort](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-dictsort)

```
{% for badge_type in badge_types|dictsort:"name" %}
      {{badge_type.name}}

      {% for badge in badge_type.badge_set.all|dictsort:"name" %}
          {{badge.name}}
      {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But, i think your problem, is the [order-with-respect-to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#order-with-respect-to)

because in the model BadgeType, you don't specified the ordering.

Comment: How would I specify the ordering of `Badge` objects from within `BadgeType`?

Comment: why do not you just remove the order_with_respect_to?